# Bash script sftp only downloading files to same directory script is in

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sftp

I have a weird problem. I am trying to download a file from a ftp server to a different directory than what the bash script is running. If I do it manually everything works fine. I can connect type

```
get sampleFile.csv /path/to/directory/
```

Trying to put that in a bash script doesn't work. I get all the same output as doing it manaully

```
/ftp/sampleFile.csv 100%  384     0.4KB/s   00:01
```

but the file isn't in the directory or anywhere that I can find on my server. I have tried

```
sftp ***** << EOF
get sampleFile.csv /path/to/directory/
quit
EOF
```

and

```
cd /path/to/directory/
sftp ***** << EOF
get sampleFile.csv
quit
EOF
```

and

```
sftp ***** << EOF
lcd /path/to/directory
get sampleFile.csv
quit
EOF
```

All of these work doing it manually.

The only thing that works is

```
sftp ***** << EOF
get sampleFile.csv
quit
EOF
```

This puts the file in the same directory the bash script is in and it shows up. Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: This is really strange. A shell script doesn't know or care about the directory it's stored in - it runs with the directory of the caller. Do you have a `cd` or `chdir` earlier in the script perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Add `lcd path/you/want/to/save/to` before the `get` line of your sftp script.

```
 ❯ sftp localhost
Connected to localhost.
# can't get sampleFile.csv because lpwd isn't what I think
sftp> get sampleFile.csv path/to/directory
File "/home/ryan/sampleFile.csv" not found.
sftp> lpwd
Local working directory: /home/ryan
# this will grab the file I want, but save it into `lpwd` again
sftp> get path/to/directory/sampleFile.csv
Fetching /home/ryan/path/to/directory/sampleFile.csv to sampleFile.csv
# pretend I want to save it locally in /tmp... so: lcd /tmp
sftp> lcd /tmp
sftp> get path/to/directory/sampleFile.csv
Fetching /home/ryan/path/to/directory/sampleFile.csv to sampleFile.csv
```